# Empty Folders are not adding to zip file android

Tags: android, zip, zipoutputstream

I am doing an Android project. I need to zip a complete folder structure of SD card.
code is able to zip the folder if any files exists inside the folder, else skips that folder.

My Folder structure is like: mnt/sdcard/Movies/Telugu/Files.

mnt/sdcard/Movies/English --> English is empty folder

I did not see English folder in output zip file.

My code:

```
public void zip() {
    try {
        // create a ZipOutputStream to zip the data to
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                _zipFile));

        zipDir(folderPath, zos);
        // close the stream
        zos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }

}

public void zipDir(String dir2zip, ZipOutputStream zos) {
    try {
        File zipDir = new File(dir2zip);
        // get a listing of the directory content
        String[] dirList = zipDir.list();
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[2156];
        int bytesIn = 0;
        // loop through dirList, and zip the files
        for (int i = 0; i < dirList.length; i++) {
            File f = new File(zipDir, dirList[i]);
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                // if the File object is a directory, call this
                // function again to add its content recursively
                String filePath = f.getPath();
                zipDir(filePath, zos);
                // loop again
                continue;
            }
            // if we reached here, the File object f was not a directory

            // create a FileInputStream on top of f
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            // create a new zip entry
            ZipEntry anEntry = new ZipEntry(f.getPath());
            // place the zip entry in the ZipOutputStream object
            zos.putNextEntry(anEntry);
            // now write the content of the file to the ZipOutputStream
            while ((bytesIn = fis.read(readBuffer)) != -1) {
                zos.write(readBuffer, 0, bytesIn);
            }
            // close the Stream
            fis.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

You basically never create a zipentry for your directories.

In the `if (f.isDirectory()) {}` section, add this:

```
zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filePath));
```

You can also put it at the beginning of the method instead, to include the root dir as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's old post but it will be good for who searching to solve problem.

You have just add dirName+"/", Yes you need just one slash to end of folder name string.

```
if(dirList.length==0){
  String path=zipDir.getPath().replace(rootDir,"");
  ZipEntry anEntry = new ZipEntry(path+"/");
  zos.putNextEntry(anEntry);
}
```